# htacess to remove 'index' on last part of url (not index.php)

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, indexing

I have problem with my rewrite htaccess. I already using a htaccess on my localhost and it works. But why it's failed on my website?

here's my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule api/(.*)/(.*)$ api/$1.php?request=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Index...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

I try to access `http://www.mywebsite.com/admin/index` or `http://www.mywebsite.com/admin/index/` and it's said page not found.. I just want to remove that index on the last part of url to be `http://www.mywebsite.com/admin/`
I'm using that htaccess code on my localhost and it's success.. why it's failed on my server?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Index...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/(.*)$ api/$1.php?request=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```